# Change status bar text color to light in iOS 9 with Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios9, xcode7, statusbar

In iOS 9, how do I change the color of the status bar text to white?

Comment: you shouldnt customise the status bar. Choose one of the status bar style available. The text color should be white, when the statusbar is on dark background.

Comment: please check my answer and tell me review @reza_darkman797

Comment: On iOS9 just this in the AppDelegate works... ```[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlack];```

Comment: Heads up - `setStatusBarStyle` is deprecated on iOS 9... use `preferredStatusBarStyle` instead.

Comment: THE STATUS BAR CONTENT IS BASED ON NAVIGATION CONTROLLER BAR STYLE. SO ALL YOU NEED TO DO IS JUST ADD THE LINE IN YOUR ViewDidLoad():  [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlack];                                                              Default is Black. ie, [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleDefault];

Answer (score 420, accepted):

If you want to change Status Bar Style from the launch screen,
You should take this way.

1. Go to `Project` -> `Target`,
2. Set `Status Bar Style` to `Light`
   [image: Project Setting]
3. Set `View controller-based status bar appearance` to `NO` in `Info.plist`.

Comment: Status Bar Style's dropdown is missing in xcode 7.2. Where I can find it?

Comment: @SonicMaster I don't know why you don't find it. I can see it in xcode 7.2 ?_?

Comment: @WanbokChoi, it was my fault. If you set your target to ipad/iphone only instead of universal, that dropdown will disappear. Thank you.

Comment: For iOS 10 you also need to add this code on every ViewController :

- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle
{
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}

Comment: @mwaqas01 You don't need. Just set `View controller-based status bar appearance` in `plist`. It works for me.

Comment: The key for the .plist file is UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance

Comment: Works with iOS 11! Thank you!

Comment: `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` to `false` was the missing ingredient for me - thanks!

Answer (score 115):

Using a `UINavigationController` and setting its navigation bar's `barStyle` to `.Black`. past this line in your `AppDelegate.m` file.

```
navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
```

If you are not using `UINavigationController` then add following code in your `ViewController.m` file.

```
- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle
{
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}
```

And call the method to this line :

```
[self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
```

Comment: Unfortunately does not work.

Comment: are you using navigation controller ? @reza_darkman797

Comment: It does work perfectly with navbar

Comment: Thanks, it's work for me 

Comment: Thanks a lot, It is working fine.

Answer (score 42):

First set

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
```

Go to your AppDelegate, find its`didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method and do:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];

}
```

and then set `View controller-based status bar appearance` equal to NO in plist.

Comment: Adding the entry to the plist is the most important part of this answer, without this then you won't be able to set the style on individual views

Comment: setStatusBarStyle is deprecated in iOS 9...

Comment: Since iOS 9, this method is deprecated. Use the ViewController method instead :

- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle {return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;}`

You will also need to add this key in your Info.plist : "UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance"

Comment: Got it Working in Xcode 8 -iOS10 (through the project properties Statusbar: Light  and in the plist ViewController-based status bar appearance:  NO.Perfect Thanks

Answer (score 37):

1. Add a key in your `info.plist` file `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` and set it to `YES`.
2. In viewDidLoad method of your ViewController add a method call:

   ```
   [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
   ```
3. Then paste the following method in `viewController` file:

   ```
   - (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle
   { 
       return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent; 
   }
   ```

Comment: This is what I wanted because I only want to change the style for that one view controller.

Comment: you can also just set the status bar style in the ViewController's .xib (i.e. instead of adding the prefferedStatusBarStyle method)

Comment: for UIStatusBarStyleLightContent, you can also select Light in the General Tab after you select your project. No code required.

Answer (score 12):

Add the key `View controller-based status bar appearance` to `Info.plist` file and make it boolean type set to `NO`.

Insert one line code in `viewDidLoad` (this works on specific class where it is mentioned)

```
 [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
```

Comment: `statusBarStyle` is readonly: `@property(readonly, nonatomic) UIStatusBarStyle statusBarStyle` in iOS9. And `setStatusBarStyle` is deprecated

Answer (score 1):

iOS Status bar has only 2 options (black and white).
You can try this in AppDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
}
```

Comment: 'setStatusBarStyle:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9.0 - Use -[UIViewController preferredStatusBarStyle]