# UINavigationBar hides under statusBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, uistatusbar

In some `UIViewController`, `UINavigationBar` hides under status bar. Here is the screenshot:

[image: <code>UINavigationBar</code> under StatusBar]

But when I change `View controller-based status bar appearance` to `YES` then `UINavigationBar` looks perfect. Here is the screenshot:

[image: black text in <code>UIStatusBar</code>]

But in this case, `textColor` of `status bar` goes change from white to black. I want white text color of status bar and also unhide `UINavigationBar` from status bar.  Is there any way to solve out it (White color of status bar and unhide `UINavigationBar`).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: YES but its not working. :(

Comment: If u dragged and dropped your navigation bar and then applied constraints to it, then its constraint issue..add some space to topConstriant

Comment: @SahebSingh I am not using constraint in any UIViewController. I am just resolving issue from existing code.

Comment: @MuhammadAdnan Please check my updated question. and I have tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19105766/ios-7-status-bar-collides-with-navigationbar  but not working.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33103831/change-status-bar-text-color-to-light-in-ios-9-with-objective-c for ios 9 specific

Comment: @MuhammadAdnan still same.

Comment: put `[[UIApplication sharedApplication]setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];` in `viewDidAppear` and try again...

Comment: override `UIViewController`'s method - `- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle`, just like this 
    `return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;`

Answer (score 2):

You can always manually set the origin of the navigation bar in viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.origin = CGPoint(0, 20)
```

Answer (score 1):

Add these keys to your project `Info.plist` and you should be ok.

```
<key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>
<string>UIStatusBarStyleLightContent</string>
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<false/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in your Appdelegate  and info.plist

in info.Plist

```
View controller-based status bar appearance to NO
```

In Appdelegate

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
```

Comment: Already added but not working.

Comment: Set  

View controller-based status bar appearance to NO

Comment: If I set View controller-based status bar appearance to NO then UINavigationBar hides under UIStatusBar