# Status bar color taking a lot of time to change in ios(only for tht first time)

Tags: ios, objective-c, statusbar

I have the following code to change the color of my status bar and it is working fine.

```
statusBarTintView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame]];
statusBarTintView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
statusBarTintView.backgroundColor = [[Color sharedInstance] navigationBarColor];
[self.window addSubview:statusBarTintView];
[statusBarTintView release];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
```

But it is taking a lot of time to change (only for the first time).
What am i doing wrong?
Can anyone help me?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19065098/status-bar-text-color-ios-7
check this post!

Answer (score 0):

1. Set the `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` to `YES` in the .plist file.
2. In the `viewDidLoad` do a `[self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate]`;
3. Add the following method:

   ```
   - (UIStatusBarStyle) preferredStatusBarStyle
   { 
        return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent; 
   }
   ```

Please refer this answers for more details.

[How to change Status Bar text color in iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17678881/how-to-change-status-bar-text-color-in-ios-7?page=1&tab=active#tab-top)

[Change status bar text color to light in iOS 9 with Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33103831/change-status-bar-text-color-to-light-in-ios-9-with-objective-c)