# statusBarStyle in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, statusbar

This is the code I written in AppDelegate class (Swift 4):

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
     UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
    goToRootViewController()
    UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = true

    UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
    UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
    GMSServices.provideAPIKey(googleMapApiKey)
    return true
}
```

but my status bar is not showing the light content I dont know what is ging on, Any help?

[image]

Comment: did you add .plist key for changing status bar

Comment: nope, I didn't change

Comment: then set it in plist

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33103831/change-status-bar-text-color-to-light-in-ios-9-with-objective-c i followed this but still not working

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## For Specific ViewController Class:

In your viewcontroller class use this code below viewDidLoad() :

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle : UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
}
```

this will show your status bar in light content

## For Whole App:

Set "View controller-based status bar appearance" Key with Value "NO" in your product's Info.plist

[image]

Then Use Following code in AppDelegate.Swift inside "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions":

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    
    UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
    return true
}
```

Comment: Yes, it works for only specific ViewController. If you want for whole app set "View controller-based status bar appearance" key in you info.plist and asign it NO, Then Simply use "UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent" in your AppDelegate.swift. Your problem will solved.

Comment: It is but i done it in appdelegate but not working in my code

Comment: Did you set "View controller-based status bar appearance" key in you info.plist with value "NO"

Comment: i try and not work, this is suggestion from X code:  `Setter for 'statusBarStyle' was deprecated in iOS 9.0: Use -[UIViewController preferredStatusBarStyle]`

Answer (score 2):

Select you project and navigate to `Target -> General -> Deployment Info`. In that `Status Bar Style` is `Default`, Change it to `Light`.

[image]

Comment: i have done this but nothing changed it still shows the dark

Answer (score 1):

Have you Change in info.plist the row **View controller-based status bar appearance** and set it to NO ?
Because this is necessary in order to change the status bar appearance

and also if you only want to change status bar on specific view controller then you can use

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Setter for 'statusBarStyle' was deprecated in iOS 9.0: Use -[UIViewController preferredStatusBarStyle]

Manually setting `UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent` under AppDelegate function `-didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` doesn't seem to work

First set in file `Info.plist`

```
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<false/>
```

Second:

```
Target -> General -> Deployment Info
```

Set `Status Bar Style` to `Light`

Answer (score 0):

use below code in didLoad of your specific controller

```
UIView *statusBar = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] valueForKey:@"statusBarWindow"] valueForKey:@"statusBar"];

    if ([statusBar respondsToSelector:@selector(setBackgroundColor:)]) {

        statusBar.backgroundColor = [self colorWithHexString:@"C2BFAB"];//set whatever color you like
       // appDel.statusBarColor = NO;
    }
```